# Ferrites losses calculation

Tags: rf-power, electronics, ferrite

I am new on RF design. I would like to know more about ferrites. I am looking for information about how to calculate ferrite losses and saturation points for a given application. I also would like to know what a good starting kit of ferrites for HF applications is.

Comment: What are you going to use the ferrites for? Fair-rite has quite a lot of information on their website for some common applications.

Comment: THe best data comes from the OEM as every part is unique.